# gridview delete command within updatepanel, and separate __doPostback() functionality

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a gridview within an updatepanel, the rows have a delete button which removes that row.

Elsewhere, I run code to insert a row.  Following this insert I run __doPostback() with the ID of the updatepanel, then in the updatepanel's load() event I call databind() on the gridview.

As soon as I implement the __doPostback() and databind, the inbuilt gridview delete stops working! :(  The actual refresh/databind when adding the row works well.

How can I overcome this? I guess something may be awry in that when clicking on the delete button, the databind is conflicting with the inbuild delete/refresh functionality?

Thanks!

EDIT: Apologies if the question isn't described well...

Essentially, I wish to have a gridview with built-in delete functionality through the datasource and command column etc. inside of an updatepanel.  I also want to update this panel seperately, but when I put in this separate update code (gridview.databind in the updatepanel.load) it breaks the standard delete functionality.  Hope that is clear :)

Comment: Can you post the code you run to insert a row? Does that code run immediately following your delete button click? I'm not quite sure how these two events relate.

Comment: The insert is a simple sqlCommand inside a USING block, followed by ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript which runs the __doPostback with an updatepanel containing the main gridview as its parameter.  This code is unrelated to the deletebutton, which is 'built-in' to the gridview through the sqldatasource and deletecommand etc.

Comment: further comment - disregarding the external code used to insert a record, the only code I've used which may be interfering with the gridview delete is on the updatepanel's load() routine.  Inside here I do a gridview.databind().  Just noticed I am getting the following error: "sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception: invalid postback or callback argument" - does that help shed any light on the issue? cheers

Answer (score 0):

You've tried put the UpdatePanelMode as Conditional and use UpdatePanel.Update() besides  the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript during your insertion block ?

Comment: Hi, disregarding the clientscript approach (this is due to me performing the update from a different aspx page altogether) it seems that when I wrap the GridViews inside an UpdatePanel - and have DataBind called on this update, it immediately breaks the delete functionality.  I can see (I think?!) why it's happening but can't think of a way of avoiding it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the event is inside of the GridView and you can't access them as easily as you can with something like a Button. To register the GridView to make the Async events you need to attach it to the ScriptManager.

To do this you use the `RegisterAsyncpostBackControl` method.

Here is a general idea of how to do it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
      <%-- your fields, etc --%>
    </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your code behind you do

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(GridView1);
}
```

It's been a while since I've done this but I believe this will allow the GridView to function as you'd expect, except you don't need the extra DataBind() I don't believe in this case.

You can also set the UpdatePanel to Conditional and fire an UpdatePanel1.Update() on top of this as Jeison suggested.

You can find some added details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386452.aspx

If you still have trouble, let us know what happened.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, unfortunately I can't get this to work (seems to make no difference). I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, everything works until I put the DataBind statements in the UpdatePanel_Load() event.. I need them there to allow me to refresh the UpdatePanel from outside the GridView...

Comment: I don't think you need the extra DataBind. The script manager should know to deal with the GridView if you attach the AsyncPostBack in the Page_Load since you always want it to be registered.

Comment: Forgot to add that I believe you can do UpdatePanel1.Update() to force a refresh, don't do DataBind()

Comment: Thanks - if I don't databind, then then gridview doesn't change.. the updatepanel is definitely refreshing (tested by a simple js alert on the updatepanel.load event)

Comment: Try putting your SqlDataSource inside of the same UpdatePanel as the GridView

Comment: Made no difference - should it have? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you calling `DataBind()` of GridView every time the `UpdatePanel` load after the insert button click, it reload the data before delete reaches the DataSource.

EDIT

If so, you can add boolean eventArgument in __doPostBack(updatePanelId, "true"). And using this you could add a condition in your updatepanel load event like

```
if(this.updatepanel1.Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "true"]
   this.gridview.databind()
```

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Oooh, we're getting very close now! This is great in that it does indeed allow the initial delete functionality to work, and also allows me to call databind() during the updatepanel.load event which refreshes the data. However once the databind and update takes place, the delete functionality breaks again! Any ideas? (tried Kirk's solution after the databind() but that didn't fix it)

Comment: Can you post the type of datasource you are binding to GridView?

Comment: It's an sqldatasource, stored procedure all done the 'easy' way :)